# Use Flyway migration on Integration Tests using H2

Tags: spring-boot, h2, flyway

I'm trying to create a in-memory database with flyway migration to perform my Spring Boot Integration tests.

But when I execute the test suite, with a single and simple test, I'm getting this error:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.5.RELEASE)

2020-11-10 21:30:48.381  INFO 3252 --- [           main] b.c.f.babysitter.AcaoIntegrationTests    : Starting AcaoIntegrationTests on DESKTOP-KG8MEOV with PID 3252 (started by vinic in C:\Users\vinic\Documents\Spring\workspace_fiap\babysitter)
2020-11-10 21:30:48.382  INFO 3252 --- [           main] b.c.f.babysitter.AcaoIntegrationTests    : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-11-10 21:30:48.619  INFO 3252 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFERRED mode.
2020-11-10 21:30:48.659  INFO 3252 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 39ms. Found 2 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-11-10 21:30:48.949  INFO 3252 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 0 (http)
2020-11-10 21:30:48.950  INFO 3252 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-11-10 21:30:48.950  INFO 3252 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.39]
2020-11-10 21:30:48.951  INFO 3252 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : Loaded Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.25] using APR version [1.7.0].
2020-11-10 21:30:48.951  INFO 3252 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
2020-11-10 21:30:48.951  INFO 3252 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
2020-11-10 21:30:48.952  INFO 3252 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020]
2020-11-10 21:30:48.989  INFO 3252 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat-1].[localhost].[/]     : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-11-10 21:30:48.989  INFO 3252 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 603 ms
2020-11-10 21:30:49.036  INFO 3252 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-2 - Starting...
2020-11-10 21:30:49.038  INFO 3252 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-2 - Start completed.
2020-11-10 21:30:49.038  INFO 3252 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:testdb'
2020-11-10 21:30:49.174  INFO 3252 --- [           main] o.f.c.internal.database.DatabaseFactory  : Database: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb (H2 1.4)
2020-11-10 21:30:49.182  INFO 3252 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbValidate     : Successfully validated 1 migration (execution time 00:00.005s)
2020-11-10 21:30:49.190  INFO 3252 --- [           main] o.f.c.i.s.JdbcTableSchemaHistory         : Creating Schema History table "PUBLIC"."flyway_schema_history" ...
2020-11-10 21:31:19.205  WARN 3252 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: 
Unable to obtain connection from database: HikariPool-2 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30003ms.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL State  : null
Error Code : 0
Message    : HikariPool-2 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30003ms.

2020-11-10 21:31:19.205  INFO 3252 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-2 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-11-10 21:31:19.206  INFO 3252 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-2 - Shutdown completed.
2020-11-10 21:31:19.206  INFO 3252 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-11-10 21:31:19.213  INFO 3252 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-11-10 21:31:19.214 ERROR 3252 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: 
Unable to obtain connection from database: HikariPool-2 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30003ms.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL State  : null
Error Code : 0
Message    : HikariPool-2 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30003ms.

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1794) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:311) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1109) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:405) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120) ~[spring-boot-test-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124) ~[spring-test-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:123) ~[spring-test-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.outputConditionEvaluationReport(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:53) ~[spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:46) ~[spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244) ~[spring-test-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:98) ~[spring-test-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:341) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:346) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:341) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:340) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:263) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$2(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:256) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:362) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$3(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:255) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:29) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:108) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:107) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:71) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:107) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:107) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:75) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248) ~[.cp/:na]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211) ~[.cp/:na]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226) ~[.cp/:na]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199) ~[.cp/:na]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:141) ~[.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98) ~[.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41) ~[.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542) ~[.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770) ~[.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464) ~[.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210) ~[.cp/:na]
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: 
Unable to obtain connection from database: HikariPool-2 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30003ms.
```

Basically, flyway is throwing an error after trying to connect to the H2 database, and, apparently, the database is currently off.

I can access the console on `localhost:8080/h2-console`, but cannot log-in, with the error message:

`Database "mem:testdb" not found, either pre-create it or allow remote database creation (not recommended in secure environments) [90149-200] 90149/90149 (Help)`

My application-test.properties (which I'm using on my test suite):

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=stars
spring.datasource.password=C0nst3llat10n

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

spring.flyway.locations=classpath:db/tests

spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=1
```

How can I avoid this to use H2 only as database testing case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out how to solve.

On my `application-test.properties`, I needed to specify `spring.flyway.*` properties to work correctly.

My changes were:

Before

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=stars
spring.datasource.password=C0nst3llat10n

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

spring.flyway.locations=classpath:db/tests

spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=1
```

After:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=stars
spring.datasource.password=C0nst3llat10n

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

spring.flyway.locations=classpath:db/tests

spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=1

spring.flyway.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.flyway.user=stars
spring.flyway.password=C0nst3llat10n
```

And it runned without errors.